# Site-to-site vpn: Able to ping AWS from onprem but other way(AWS to on prem not working)

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, aws-site-to-site

I set up site-to-site vpn to connect to my on-premises from the aws instance. The route table, network acl, sec group, etc. all looking good. I noticed that I am able to ping aws using aws private ip from my on-premises. But, I am unable to ping on-premises from ec2 instance?

> ping AWS-PRIVATE-IP from On-Prem "works"
>
> ping ON-PREM-PRIVATE-IP from aws "does not work"

What could be the possible reason for the failure, as I crossed-check everything and it is look good.

Route Table:
[image]

Network ACL:

[image]
[image]

Comment: NACLs allow traffic both ways?

Comment: HI @Paolo: Please check the update. Yes, both are allowed.